# socket.io with c++?

Tags: c++, node.js, socket.io

Please tell me can I wrote some c++ console application and connect on some node.js server(on nodester example) which using socket.io? Some (C/C++) -> (node.js/socket.io) library? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the socket.io module in your C++ program, or that you want to connect to another program (made in node.js/socket.io) with a socket?

Comment: I don't know if it's still relevant, but there is [a socket.io client library in C++](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/) now.

Answer (score 3):

[boost::asio based c++ socket.io client](https://github.com/uning/socket.io-client-cpp)

Comment: Poco version: https://github.com/gelldur/socket.io-poco

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. FWIW, an [open-source project does this in Objective-C](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc), which should at least give you some ideas on how to do it in C/C++.

Comment: Can you give me any example of using that codeand connecting on server?

Comment: In https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc/blob/master/SocketIO.m see the function "connectToHost".

Comment: The asker sounds like he may not have enough experience with C++ to avoid being confused by the Objective-C syntax.