# Can I keep pushing data from the server to the same connection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, push

I'm setting up a stock-ticker like web-page, written in JavaScript.  I am also writing the server that the page talks to, in C++.

I would like to make the web page efficient, such that it makes sends single subscription message to the app server, and then holds a keep-alive connection open, constantly receiving inbound data pushed from the app server.

At the moment, I have to re-issue the web clients' subscription call every time I receive data from the server.  The problem is that each time the XHR object hits readyState(4), the call is effectively completed.  Any data arriving at the web page after this is ignored.  The web-client can resend data and that resets the object, but the send is unnecessary, and is only being used to reset the XHR object.

I would like to know if it is possible to somehow reset the existing XHR object, and put it into a state where it expects more inbound data, so that when more data is pushed to the web page, the web page responds and processes it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.  Note: Not using JQuery on this project.

Comment: Not with XHR (actually, not with HTTP). You're looking for [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).

Comment: @bfavaretto, That should have been an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: @epascarello Sometimes I'm just too lazy! :) Added something slightly better as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend looking into Websockets, especially a library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which encapsulates various browser's implementations of Websocket transports into a single API (WS, JSON, JSONP, Flash and Long Polling).

Socket.io client libraries should be now be supported by all major browsers. Your only challenge might be locating a C++ specific server implementation. Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216779/socket-io-with-c) SO question might be of some help

Otherwise, your only other option is long-polling or comet on the client with a suitable server-side implementation that would scale (i.e. something like an event driven server like NginX as opposed to a thread-per-connection architecture.)

I do appreciate that you are committed to C++ but my humble advise would be to investigate Node.js as it can and does provide a very performant solution with very little effort.

HTH and all the best.

Comment: Agreed, web-sockets is the future, and I've consciously avoided it because of it's lack of support in older browsers.  I appreciate the response, I'm going to have to keep looking for some other options to make the long polling more efficient.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a one-off protocol: one request, one response, and you're done. If you want to keep a connection open, you can use Websockets ([MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets), [client-side code example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)). However consider it won't be supported on older browsers (IE, for example, just started supporting Websockets on version 10), so you'll probably need to implement a fallback using XHR and [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

Comment: I read somewhere that XHR can be fudged into constant streaming by making the browser think that a large file is being delivered in chunks, but I cannot find an example.  WebSockets is ideal, but I need that backwards support at least this year.  Thanks for your help.